# Avoid counting duplicate clicks SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a data like the below:

```
date                      id         process      name
2022-01-01 12:23:33       12         security     John
2022-01-01 12:25:33       12         security     John
2022-01-01 12:27:33       12         security     John
2022-01-01 12:29:33       12         security     John
2022-01-01 14:04:45       12         security     John
2022-01-05 03:53:11       12         Infra        Sasha
2022-01-05 03:57:30       12         Infra        Sasha
2022-01-06 12:23:33       12         Infra        Sasha
```

The data with date difference of 10 mins for same values in the other fields are basically multi clicks and only the first one needs to be considered.

Expected result:

```
2022-01-01 12:23:33       12         security     John
2022-01-01 14:04:45       12         security     John
2022-01-05 03:53:11       12         Infra        Sasha
2022-01-06 12:23:33       12         Infra        Sasha
```

I know we can use datediff() but i don't know how to group them by data thats same in the rest of the fields. I don't know where to start this logic.
Can someone help me get this please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `LAG()` to peek at a value of a previous row, according to a subgroup an ordering within the each subgroup. For example:

```
select *
from (
  select *, lag(date) over(partition by id, process order by date) as pd from t
) x
where pd is null or date > pd + interval '10 minute'
```

Result:

```
 date                 id  process   name   pd                  
 -------------------- --- --------- ------ ------------------- 
 2022-01-05 03:53:11  12  Infra     Sasha  null                
 2022-01-06 12:23:33  12  Infra     Sasha  2022-01-05 03:57:30 
 2022-01-01 12:23:33  12  security  john   null                
 2022-01-01 14:04:45  12  security  john   2022-01-01 12:29:33
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/K3V8zbto).

Comment: @AlisonGrey, there is a subtle nuance with this approach here. If you have a lot of adjacent rows, so that each pair is less than 10 minutes apart, you can have a set of rows that span a much longer period and all of them would still be grouped together. Say, 12:20, 12:25, 12:30, 12:35, 12:40, 12:45, 12:50, 12:55, 13:00 would be grouped together, even though they collectively cover 40 minutes. If this is what you want - great.

Comment: Ah I see your point here - @VladimirBaranov
My expectation is slightly differed - yes . 
In your example I'd still want to see those that are after 12:35 and 12:50 considered. Is there a way to query to resolve this part?

Comment: @AlisonGrey, If in the example above you want to see three or four lines in the result, you can simply round your times to 10th minutes (12:20, 12:30, 12:40, etc) and group by these rounded times. Without any `LAG` function. Maybe ask another question with relevant sample data that covers this case and explain what your expected result should be.